# timer not working properly,Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, timer, avfoundation

I'm trying to make a timer count **up** the seconds I'm holding on a button.(holding to record a video) and its just not working correctly...sometimes its skipping seconds & sometimes just freezes and then speeding up to catch up ...i really need your help solving this, i need the timer to be as fluid and as constant as it can get, thanks.

```
//Timer Variables:
    var recordingCounter : Timer!
    var minutes: Int = 0
    var seconds: Int = 0
    var counterString : String = ""

func longTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
        if sender.state == .ended {
            print("UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded")

            recordingCounter.invalidate()

            seconds = 0
            minutes = 0

            if self.timerView.alpha == 1.0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

                self.timerView.alpha = 0.0
                self.timerView.isHidden = true
                self.recordingCounter.invalidate()

                self.seconds = 0
                self.minutes = 0

                self.counterString = "00:00"
                self.countingLabel.text = self.counterString
            })
            }

    return

        }else if sender.state == .began {

            timerView.isHidden = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

                self.timerView.alpha = 1.0

            })

            print("UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.")

            recordingCounter = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

func updateCounter() {

        seconds += 1
        if seconds == 60 {

            minutes += 1
            seconds = 0

        }

        let secondsString = seconds > 9 ? "\(seconds)" : "0\(seconds)"
        let minutesString = minutes > 9 ? "\(minutes)" : "0\(minutes)"

        counterString = "\(minutesString):\(secondsString)"
        countingLabel.text = counterString

    }
```

btw I'm running a VideoPreviewLayer of my custom AVFoundation Camera in the same time.. might cause the problems?

Comment: Don't use a `Timer` if you need precise measurements. Use a `CADisplayLink`.

Comment: Try updating the label asynchronously in the updateCounter method.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys how do i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Timer` works in this same `DispatchQueue` as user interaction (for example scrolling in the `UITableView`, tap in the `UIGestureRecognizer` or holding on a `UIbutton`). So when the user does anything, then the `Timer` will freeze for a moment.

You can solve this problem by using, for example, [AsyncTimer](https://github.com/Decybel07/AsyncTimer).

Comment: Technically timers are [attached to run loops](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1418468-add). Run loops drive threads which drive dispatch queues.

Answer (score 0):

You can call fire()

```
recordingCounter = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: duration, repeats: true, block: {[unowned self] (timer) in 

}) 

recordingCounter.fire()
```